# CFArray takeRetainedValue() removal causing crashes

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2, core-graphics

I've been using this block of code to find a certain active application's window ID for months now:

```
let info = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(CGWindowListOption(kCGWindowListOptionAll), CGWindowID(0)).takeRetainedValue()
            for dict in info as! [ [ String : AnyObject ] ] {
                if let windowName = dict["kCGWindowName"] as? String{
                    if(windowName == "MyWindowName"){
                        let windowID = dict["kCGWindowNumber"] as! Int
                        println("found window, window number: \(windowID)")
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
```

As of a recent Swift update, however, the `takeRetainedValue()` and its counterpart `takeUnretainedValue()` have seemingly been removed. Every post about it online that I can find says just removing the call should leave it working with more or less the same behavior, but when I do, the application always crashes with the lovely "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" error on the "for dict in info" line, before the loop can even start.

I've spent hours and hours trying to solve the issue, and I've found a bunch of leads but none of them have taken my anywhere. I've gathered that it's got to do with the removal of `takeRetainedValue()` leaving me with an unmanaged `CFArray` object, but I'm still learning, and clueless as to where to go from here.

Is there any way to fix the issue I'm encountering, or if not, another approach that I should be using entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some funky changes to accessing CoreFoundation objects in Swift 2.  You no longer need to take a retained or unretained value from a `CFArray`, you can bridge it directly to a Swift array.  You're getting a crash because you're trying to cast a `CFArray` to a `[[String : AnyObject]]` at runtime and it's returning `nil`.

`CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` returns `CFArray?` (an optional `CFArray`).  Trying to bridge `CFArray?` to `[AnyObject]` will fail, but bridging it to an optional Swift array (`[AnyObject]?`) will work.  But in order to iterate through that array we must unwrap it.  Here I check if the `CFArray` returned by `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` can be unwrapped and bridged to `[AnyObject]!`:

```
if let info = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(.OptionAll, CGWindowID(0)) as [AnyObject]! {
    for dict in info {
        if let windowName = dict[kCGWindowName as String] as? String {
            if (windowName == "MyWindowName"){
                let windowID = dict[kCGWindowNumber as String] as? Int
                print("found window, window number: \(windowID)")
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If for whatever reason `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` returns nil, we won't try to iterate through it.

Also note that the `CFString` constants `kCGWindowName` and `kCGWindowNumber` can be bridged to a Swift `String` object no problem.  It's better to use the constants than hardcoded strings, as the value of the constant may change over time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and the great suggestions! It's all making much, much more sense now.

How does casting those `CFString`s to Swift `String`s prevent future changes from causing problems, though? What does it matter what type of String object it is if the value itself is what may be changed?

Comment: @JackB.Cousineau In your original code you pass have `"kCGWindowName"`, which is a string literal.  What (I believe) you actually want is the constant [`kCGWindowName`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Optional_Window_List_Keys), which points to some `CFString` value in the SDK.  Apple provides constants for these values in case the underlying string representation changes over the different SDK version.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Thanks for all your help!